# TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

Tags: oracle, listener, oracle18c

I am trying to configure Oracle database 18C on Azure cloud VM.
I have installed the Oracle database and now I am trying to configure Listener
I have set up a public static IPv4 address for the VM
When I am trying to add the IP address in the listener and tnsnames file, I am getting this error

```
Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=IP)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   64-bit Windows Error: 49: Unknown error
```

Here is my listener.ora and tsnnames.ora file configuration.

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:E:\app\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
     (SID_DESC =
             (SID_NAME = ORCL)
             )
                       
  )


LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = IPaddress)(PORT = 1521))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\Oracle\Oracle18C\log
```

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = IPaddress)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Ping is working for the IP address when I try with my local machine
When I tried using the hostname 'oraclevm' then listener was able to start up

Answer (score 1):

the following a working example for listener.ora

```
[oracle@ol7-19 ~]$ cd $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
[oracle@ol7-19 admin]$ more listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /home/oracle/Downloads/19c/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol7-19.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
```

Comment: My server's local domain name is oraclevm but I don't have any domain name associated with my IP address, what to do in this case or maybe I am getting something wrong.

Comment: you can ping local hostto get physical ips

Comment: I have the physical IP of the server, I researched this issue and got to know that -

Public static IP is assigned to a network interface on the Azure
And my Virtual machine has a Private static IP
When I ping public IP my VM responds
But When to try to use Public IP in the listener file, it throws an error because Public IP is not known to VM's OS.
I tried enabling IP forwarding in the Azure Portal but still can not tnsping from outside of the local network.